# Should I create redirect IO handles and lpEnvironment after the call to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()?

Tags: winapi, service

I'm looking now at the sources of wininetd: http://4coder.org/c-c-source-code/27/wininetd-0.7/wininetd.c.html , line 408. It seems strange that CreateProcessAsUserA() arguments: lpEnvironment, si.hStdInput, etc. are filled after the call to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(), creating unneeded code duplication.

Does it have any special meaning? For example, affects handle inheritance or breaks security?

```
if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(husr)) {
    winet_log(WINET_LOG_ERROR, "[%s] unable to impersonate user: user='%s' err='%s'\n",
          WINET_APPNAME, pm->user, emsg = winet_get_syserror());
    free(emsg);
    CloseHandle(husr);
    return -1;
}
if (winet_create_stdhandles(asock, &si.hStdInput, &si.hStdOutput, &si.hStdError) < 0) {
    RevertToSelf();
    CloseHandle(husr);
    return -1;
}
if (!(env = winet_prepare_env(pm, asock, saddr))) {
    RevertToSelf();
    CloseHandle(husr);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);
    return -1;
}
if (!CreateProcessAsUserA(husr, NULL, pm->cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | DETACHED_PROCESS,
              env, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    winet_log(WINET_LOG_ERROR, "[%s] unable to create process as user: cmdln='%s' user='%s' err='%s'\n",
          WINET_APPNAME, pm->cmdline, pm->user, emsg = winet_get_syserror());
    free(emsg);
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(env);
    RevertToSelf();
    CloseHandle(husr);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);
    return -1;
}
RevertToSelf();
CloseHandle(husr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation of pipes and environment blocks is sensitive to the current user of the calling thread, hense the need to impersonate first.  Also, the code is calling `CreateProcess()` vs `CreateProcessAsUser()` depending on whether impersonation is being used.  So it makes sense that portions of the code are duplicated. On the other hand, the code could certainly have been written in such a way to reduce duplication of code without changing the overall meaning of the original code, eg:

```
static int winet_serve_client(portmap_t *pm, SOCKET asock, struct sockaddr_in *saddr) {
    HANDLE husr = NULL;
    char *emsg;
    LPVOID env;
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    BOOL impersonating = FALSE;
    BOOL created;

    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.lpDesktop = "";
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (winet_user_handle(pm, &husr) >= 0) {
        if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(husr)) {
            winet_log(WINET_LOG_ERROR, "[%s] unable to impersonate user: user='%s' err='%s'\n", WINET_APPNAME, pm->user, emsg = winet_get_syserror());
            free(emsg);
            CloseHandle(husr);
            return -1;
        }
        impersonating = TRUE;
    }

    if (winet_create_stdhandles(asock, &si.hStdInput, &si.hStdOutput, &si.hStdError) < 0) {
        if (impersonating) RevertToSelf();
        if (husr) CloseHandle(husr);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(env = winet_prepare_env(pm, asock, saddr))) {
        if (impersonating) RevertToSelf();
        if (husr) CloseHandle(husr);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);
        return -1;
    }

    if (husr) {
        created = CreateProcessAsUserA(husr, NULL, pm->cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | DETACHED_PROCESS, env, NULL, &si, &pi));
    } else {
        created = CreateProcessA(NULL, pm->cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | DETACHED_PROCESS, env, NULL, &si, &pi));
    }

    if (!created) {
        emsg = winet_get_syserror();
        if (husr) {
            winet_log(WINET_LOG_ERROR, "[%s] unable to create process as user: cmdln='%s' user='%s' err='%s'\n", WINET_APPNAME, pm->cmdline, pm->user, emsg);
        } else {
            winet_log(WINET_LOG_ERROR, "[%s] unable to create process: cmdln='%s' err='%s'\n", WINET_APPNAME, pm->cmdline, emsg);
        }
        free(emsg);
        FreeEnvironmentStrings(env);
        if (impersonating) RevertToSelf();
        if (husr) CloseHandle(husr);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);
        return -1;
    }

    if (impersonating) RevertToSelf();
    if (husr) CloseHandle(husr);

    if (impersonating) {
        winet_log(WINET_LOG_MESSAGE, "[%s] process created: user='%s' cmdln='%s'\n", WINET_APPNAME, pm->user, pm->cmdline);
    } else {
        winet_log(WINET_LOG_MESSAGE, "[%s] process created: cmdln='%s'\n", WINET_APPNAME, pm->cmdline);
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    FreeEnvironmentStrings(env);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
    CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested: pipes and env. inherit fine even if called before ImpersonateLoggedOnUser. Since wininetd doesn't load the user profile, inheriting the 'local system' env. seems safe to me.